# Magento 2.0 first installation on shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, magento2

I have installed/reinstalled my first magento 2.0 on one of my shared hosting server. I followed installation guide from magento devdocs. Everything seemed to bo ok, but when I visit site I dont see any images, css, scripts running in the background. 
Ok, it must be .htaccess, I check my configuration, it seems to be ok, then I inspected elements and saw 403 errors,

> dev.testing.com/two/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/sl_SI/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico
>   403 (Forbidden)

ok check .htaccess again, then I check in the file manager and saw all those files missing, can someone give me a hint what am I missing, doing wrong for the past days?

Comment: You can [redeploy the static view files](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html) and check the file manager to see if they're present. After that, [check ownership and permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html#zip-perms) again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these commands
your Magento install dir/

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

after these commands you have to give permission to var and pub folders by using

```
chmod 777 -R var
```

AND

```
chmod 777 -R pub
```